# Regular expression to extract span tag value

Tags: c#, html, regex

i need to extract nHKS8cG006 using c#
from  `"Content from Eikon: <span class="tr-pnac" id="x2">ID:nHKS8cG006</span>"`
here "Content from Eikon should be included as a part of regular expression and class name name of span remains same all the time, but id value may vary, it would be like x18,17,x96 and so on.

Thank you.

Comment: @TheGeneral 
 am confined to add extra dll to my solution hence help me to correct this
Regex(@"(?<=(Content\s+(from\s*Eikon)[:]?\s+)<span class=\'tr-pnac\' id='(.*?)'>\[(ID:)?)n[A-Za-z0-9]+(?=\])</span>", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);

Comment: And what is your problem? What did you try to achieve this? We´re not doing your job here. Apart from this here´s a tip: to extract or parse information from HTML, use an HTML-parser, e.g. HtmlAgilityPack.

Comment: regex for this is actually quite simple: https://regexr.com/3uge7

Comment: @Chris tnk you.

Comment: your welcome! you can upvode my comment :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use code below without additional components. It uses standard classes from System.Xml.

```
var txt = "Content from Eikon: <span class=\"tr-pnac\" id=\"x2\">ID:nHKS8cG006</span>";
var xml = new System.Xml.XmlDocument();
xml.LoadXml($"<root>{txt}</root>");
var spanNodes = xml.DocumentElement.SelectNodes("//span[contains(@class, 'tr-pnac')]");
//or
//var spanNodes = xml.DocumentElement.SelectNodes("//span[@class='tr-pnac']");
foreach (XmlNode n in spanNodes)
{
    System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(n.InnerText.Substring(3));
}
```

Here is Regex version for you:

```
var txt = "Content from Eikon: <span class=\"tr-pnac\" id=\"x2\">ID:nHKS8cG006</span>";
var regex = new Regex("Content from Eikon: <span class=\"tr-pnac\" id=\"[a-zA-Z0-9]+\">ID:(?<id>[a-zA-Z0-9]+)</span>", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
var match = regex.Match(txt);
System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(match.Groups["id"].Value);
```

Comment: thank you. But, in realtime there are multiple span tags with classname tr-pnac, but i want to extract value of that span which has pattern `Content from Eikon: <span class=\"tr-pnac\" id=\"x2\">ID:nHKS8cG006</span`

Answer (score 0):

it's better to use Html Agility Pack [LINK](http://html-agility-pack.net/)

regular expression for parsing HTML is not a good practice.

```
// From File
var doc = new HtmlDocument();
doc.Load(filePath);

// From String
var doc = new HtmlDocument();
doc.LoadHtml(html);

// From Web
var url = "http://html-agility-pack.net/";
var web = new HtmlWeb();
var doc = web.Load(url);

string whatYouNeed = doc.GetElementbyId("x2");
```